# What software will let me open old Photoshop PSD files?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, windows

I found some old PSD files that I used to work with in Photoshop in the past. I think it was version 6 or CS that I had for my online class on the internet. I still have the software with them but it only works on an old Windows version. I have a new computer with Windows 10.

What open source or a free software do you recommend me to open them? Or can I install the old Photoshop on Windows 10?

Comment: You might be able to install the old version of Photoshop using compatibility mode in Windows 10.  Try that.

Answer (score 4):

I would just download the current Photoshop free trial from Adobe - This will give you 7 days to open them and save out as a format that is useful for you going forward.

Answer (score 2):

GIMP reads PSDs to some extent. Surely all flashy features will be left out or misuderstood, but bitmap data from the layers transfer to GIMP's layers. Try it, it's freeware.

Also ON1 Perfect Layers and Serif Affinity Photo read PSDs. They have functional limited time demos available.

Installing old version of software is a risk if you have a new one already in use. At least be sure that you have a proper system backup available in case that your new version gets sick. Preferably use an old computer for old software.

ADDENDUM

Adobe has in Photoshop had a long term compatibility option in the Save as -dialog. I do not know how those files are saved. Another answer suggests to try at first with Photoshop. Of course this is the best option for first try assuming it's not already proven to be impossible or useless.

Comment: Or a virtual machine.  VirtualBox is free and has good support for Windows, including Windows XP.  All you need is a Windows XP install CD.